# Oscillator output voltage levels

Tags: oscillator

I am investigating some circuit we have with a USB HUB component: USB2504A-JT (please search google, can't attach link) that using this oscillator- [CPPC7LTA7BP-24.0000TS](http://www.cardinalxtal.com/uploads/files/cpp.pdf)

I measured on the oscillator those voltages:
VDD (pin 4)- 3.34V, OE (pin 1 -NC)- 2.95V, Output (pin 3)- 24Mhz moving from 0.8V to 2.4V compared to GND of the component (pin 2).

This output doesn't fit the datasheet, which mentioned:
max VOL=0.4V
min VHL= 3.3-0.4=2.9V
Please see attached picture of the osccilator connections and the relevant part from the DS.
[image]
(C323 PN is NFM21PC105B1A3)

Any idea why it happens? Do you think that the USB hub component has something to do with those voltage levels? (the CLKIN_EN pin is pulled high as it supposed to be)

Maybe I missed something and the OE of the osccilator must be pulled up/down?

Please tell me if you can think on any explanation.

Comment: How did you measure that signal? With what equipment?

Comment: using oscilloscope with a regular probe

Comment: What equipment means precisely that. Clearly you are using an o scope.

Comment: MSO6014A Mixed Signal Oscilloscope: 100 MHz, 4 Analog and 16 Digital Channels

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite likely that the combination of a 100 MHz oscilloscope bandwidth and the loading capacitance of the x1 probe produce this apparent error in the amplitude of the 24 MHz signal. The 100 MHz bandwidth is quoted as the 3 dB bandwidth so this will cause a perceived amplitude reduction and it is likely that the oscillator module won't be specified with up to 20 pF typical probe capacitance. Try running it with a x10 probe to see if it improves.

Comment: It seems like it make a change, but now I get the freq in voltage levels of -0.5V to 3.75V. Also doesn't match the DS.

Comment: It can be a problem with some o-scopes measuring the output amplitude correctly. I've had problems with 100 MHz Tek scopes with "apparent" overshoot above and below the rails. I don't know if a spring probe earth came with your probe kit but it might be advisable to use this.

Comment: ....make sure probe compensation is properly adjusted . What in time domain is the "spike" to be tuned out, in frequency domain is matching high frequency gain to lower end one.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the part of your question about the Output Enable (OE):

According to page 4 of the datasheet, you need to pull pin 1(OE) high to enable the oscillator.

This table:

[image]

"Input Characteristics (Pin 1):"

"VIH,  High–Level Input  Voltage TO ENABLE OUTPUT   OPEN"

I do not think this explains why your output signal is different from what the datasheet describes.

Comment: I see, but when I leave it float - I can still see 24Mhz freq at the output (and I measure 3V at this pin, which should be at least 0.7*VDD = 2.3V). So my guess that it is fine, but maybe I'm wrong. For your understanding, do I have to define it and not leave it floating?

Comment: It is almost always better to connect such inputs to the correct logic level than to leave them floating.  From your description, the input "floats up" and appears to operate correctly.  If that were guaranteed by the manufacturer (because the chip has a built in pull up, for example) then leaving it unconnected would be fine.

Comment: I've only answered the simple part of your question.  That still doesn't explain the difference in the signal levels.  You should probably take a closer look at the tips that @Andyaka has given you.

Comment: See sector "Pull-Up (pin 1)" at the 4th row from the end. I think it means it have internal pull up, isn't it?